Relationship Between Number of Sides of grid shapes and axes within noncartesian coordinate systems?
The standard, cartesian coordinate grid creates "squares" by connection any 4 adjacent lattice points. Thus, taking any 4 of these adjacent squares (effectively forming a larger, 2x2 square), we can see that drawing lines through the center of the "box" effectively touches each of the sides of the square; it never diverges from sides of the box. However, if we instead use equilateral triangles, the origin will pass through the center of the centermost triangle. There are also 3 axes when graphing on a triangular coordinate grid. Additonally, triangular grids use the center of the triangle to show location (meaning the origin is the center of the "middle" triangle), while the startard grid uses a combination of lattice points.
Regardless of number of sides, the axes always form perpendicularly to the sides of the shape (Paralells will occur in even-sided shapes, but there are always perpendiculars). Here's a short table of the ratio of n-sided coordinate grid chapels on number of axes needed to graph on that point:



Number of Sides
Number of Axes needed to plot
Shape Center or Lattice Points?




2
DNE (assuming real coordinates; nonreal may differ)
(nonreal)


3
3
Shape Center


4
2
Lattice Points


5
5
Shape Center


6
3
Lattice Points



...and so on.
How do I approach proving that for shaped with an even number of sides, there are n/2 axes needed, while odd-sided shapes have n axes? Can I prove that only odd-sided shapes can have origins in the center of the shape rather than an intersection of them (i.e. hexagons)? Would there be a way to use limit functions to effectively prove the existence of a corrdinate grid that used circles and had infinitely many axes?
